# Concatenate different variables into a single variable in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to bind the values of three input fields into a single variable and then I will store it in database... actually I have three value first is of day second is of month and third is of year

**just like that**

> 12 ---> day
>
> 09 ---> month
>
> 1990 ---> year

I want to store in database under single table like that
12-09-1996

**here is my code**

```
if(isset($_POST["reg-btn"])){
        $name=$_POST["name"];
        $lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
        $mail=$_POST["mail"];
        $pass=$_POST["pass"];
        $repass=$_POST["repass"];
        $country=$_POST["country"];
        $city=$_POST["city"];
        $day=$_POST["day"];
        $month=$_POST["month"];
        $year=$_POST["year"];
        $gender=$_POST["gender"];
        //echo '<script>alert("hello")</script>';
        $DOB+="$day."-".$month."-".$year";
        $arr= array($name,$lastname,$mail,password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT),$country,$city,$DOB,$gender);
        $SPS=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO signup (name,lastname,email,password,country,city,DOB,gender) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $SPS->execute($arr);
```

Comment: try `$DOB=$day."-".$month."-".$year;`

Comment: @ChetanAmeta not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your DOB field is a ***varchar*** then your need to write it like

```
$DOB = $day . '-' . $month . '-' . $year;
```

If your DOB field is ***date*** type then you can't store like `12-09-1996`

for that you need to write

```
    $DOB =  $year. '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
```

because MySql store's date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Coming to your problem you wrote it wrong

```
$DOB+="$day."-".$month."-".$year"; // this is wrong
```

it should be `$DOB = $day . '-' . $month . '-' . $year;`

Answer (score 0):

instead `$DOB+="$day."-".$month."-".$year";`
should be `$DOB = $day . '-' . $month . '-' . $year;`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $DOB = $day."-".$month."-".$year;
```

i hope it helps you.it must be working

Answer (score 0):

In your table if your data type is date then you can write like

$DOB = $year."-".$month."-".$day;

if datatype is varchar then:

$DOB = $day."-".$month."-".$year;